# How can I include two types of contribution in a single report

Tags: civicontribute, civireport, searchkit

[image: Contribution report configuration]

I have Contacts with 2 types of Contributions.

A) Contribution with CONTRIBUTION SOURCE = keyword

B) Contribution with CONTRIBUTION NOTE = keyword

**How can I include both types of CONTRIBUTIONS in a single Report?**

As far as I have checked, I can't search for both, because it is logical AND (I'd need OR for that).

P.S. Alternatively, I'd like to open CONTRIBUTIONS where SOURCE and NOTE is side by side and I can manually adjust SOURCE until it is uniform (contains keyword).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SearchKit is your friend!  It can do 'or' in the search.

See [this](https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/search#/create/Contribution?params=%7B%22version%22:4,%22select%22:%5B%22id%22%5D,%22orderBy%22:%7B%7D,%22where%22:%5B%5B%22OR%22,%5B%5B%22source%22,%22%3D%22,%22thing1%22%5D,%5B%22Contribution_Note_entity_id_01.note%22,%22%3D%22,%22thing2%22%5D%5D%5D%5D,%22groupBy%22:%5B%5D,%22join%22:%5B%5B%22Note%20AS%20Contribution_Note_entity_id_01%22,%22LEFT%22,%5B%22id%22,%22%3D%22,%22Contribution_Note_entity_id_01.entity_id%22%5D,%5B%22Contribution_Note_entity_id_01.entity_table%22,%22%3D%22,%22%27civicrm_contribution%27%22%5D%5D%5D,%22having%22:%5B%5D%7D) :

[image]

Comment: Looks promising. Where do I find this SearchKit? 

Is it a core function in newer versions (I currently run 5.37.2), or should it be installed separately?

Comment: Yes, SearchKit is core functionality but is disabled by default so you will need to enable it on the extensions page (Administer > System Settings > Extensions). It is evolving rapidly, so you'll get the best results if you update to the latest version of CiviCRM. Documentation here: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/the-user-interface/search-kit/

Comment: This is a very good tool. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you're looking for: https://civicrm.org/blog/titania/civicrm%E2%80%99s-powerful-custom-reporting-helps-create-targeted-groups-for-year-end

You can create two separate groups for each type. Then, include both on the include / exclude custom search page. **Search -> Custom Search -> Include / Exclude**

[image: include exclude search]

You can create include / exclude searches and save the results as a "super smart group".

**EDIT:**

You can alternatively use the "Advanced Search" feature to display results as ***contributions***, and use the ***contributions*** table to specify specific contribution record criteria (Including Source).

Don't forget to select **"OR"** as your search operator.

You can then select all contibution records and export them, selecting the fields you want to export.
[image: advanced search]

[image: Contribution export]

This may not have every single thing you need, but you can always find other criteria to help narrow down your search. And maybe get you a bit closer?

Comment: Thanks. However, this would return a group of CONTACTS while I need to get CONTRIBUTIONS. (Not even all contributions of specific contacts, but specific contributions.)

Answer (score 0):

You can find both sets of Contacts via SearchBuilder (which is not visible in menu on recent versions but can still be accessed via /civicrm/contact/search/builder?reset=1

[image]

Not sure if that gets you close enough to what you need

Comment: Thanks. However, this search returns CONTACTS while I need to get CONTRIBUTIONS.
(Also unexpected error while searching with wildcard in Contribution Note, will create a separate issue.)

Comment: then Greyson's answer is better